# Adding data to dynamic tables in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, excel, entity-framework

I want to update a database based on an Excel input file. The file's sheet names correspond to table names in the db. Each db table contains different columns, but are in corresponding order with the Excel columns. Is there a way to dynamically select the table to which to add a new entity?

The code I have thusfar to dynamically create an entity (untested, so I hope):

```
int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;                           
for (int r = 7; r < rowCount; r++)
{
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("DataGrabber." + xlWorksheet.Name.Remove(xlWorksheet.Name.Length - 1)));
    Type type = obj.GetType();
    IList<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>(type.GetProperties());
    int c = 1;

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        try
        {
            property.SetValue(obj, (int)xlRange.Cells[r, c].Value2());
        } catch
        {
            property.SetValue(obj, (decimal)xlRange.Cells[r, c].Value2());
        }
        c++;
    }
    context.[dynamic table name].AddOrUpdate(obj); ///// This is my DbContext, how to select the right table based on the type of ob              
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Set() method to add to a dynamic Table Type.

```
var query = context.Set(type);
query.Add(obj);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Only downfall is that the AddOrUpdate() method is not available, so the table needs to be emptied before the programme is run. The application is also hella slow, but that's something for another post.